# Does Mailchimp have a send API is Automation the way to go?

Tags: laravel, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I was about to start developing my companies website which is currently in research phase. I was researching with the MailChimp API (https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/) but did not find the API for using a send mail function by manager told me that it was present in our previous version of the company's website.

I came across Automation in MailChimp (https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/automations/#%20) can this be used to make a send email request, but I don't see the option for setting email send time in the api.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

welcome!

If i get you right, you want to send mails / notifications from Laravel using MailChimp?

This can be done quite easily using [this composer package](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api), but it's not bound to Laravel.

Just run in your CLI:

`composer require drewm/mailchimp-api`

And then you can do calls to MailChimp API v3 like this:

```php
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
$result = $MailChimp->get('lists');
$list_id = 'b1234346';

$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => 'davy@example.com',
                'status'        => 'subscribed',
            ]);
```

If you want some more Newsletter functionalities you can use the [spatie/laravel-newsletter package:](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter)

`composer require spatie/laravel-newsletter`

and then follow the documentation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just one question this doesn't seem to be officially supported package is it worth using in a production website other than that it is a perfect solution